# Операция сложения чисел в 100-ричной системе счисления

Tags: c++, системы-счисления

**Постановка задачи:**
Предположим, что нам даны 2 числа в 100-ричной системе счисления: 1 25 68 и -5 77 99,и мы должны их сложить. В моем, пока что, псевдокоде х1=1,х2=25,х3=68 и у1=-5, у2=77,у3=99.Число могут быть так положительным,так отрицательным.Если отрицательное,то перед х1 стоит знак минус.
Честно говоря, операция сложения работает так же как это было в 10-ричной системе счисления,только фигурирует везде 100 вместо 10.
**В чем вопрос?**
Верно ли написан псевдокод под эту задачу и можно ли вывести единый общий случай всех этих операций,без всего этого множества if и else и **КАК**???
**Код:**

```
if((x1>0 && y1>0) || (x1<0 && y1<0))
{
    z3=(x3+y3)%100
    z2=(x2+y2)%100 + (x3+y3)/100
    z1=abs(x1+y1)%100 + abs(x2+y2)/100
    z0=(x1+y1)/100
    if(z0==0 && (x1<0 && y1<0)) {z1*=-1; if(z1==0){z2*=-1; if(z2==0)z3*=-1;}
}
else if(x1<0 || y1<0)
{
    if(abs(x1)>abs(y1)){
    if(sign(x1)==1){
    z3=x3 + sign(y1)*y3;
    z2=x2 + sign(y1)*y2;
    z1=x1+y1
    if(z3<0 && z1!=0) {z3+=100;z2-=1;}
    else if(z2<0 && z1!=0) {z2+=100; z1-=1;}}
    else if(sign(x1)==-1 && z1==0){z2*=-1;if(z2==0)z3*=-1;}}
    
    else if(abs(x1)<abs(y1)){
    if(sign(x1)==1){
    z3=sign(y1)*x3 + y3;
    z2=sign(y1)*x2 + y2;
    z1=x1+y1
    if(z3<0 && z1!=0) {z3+=100;z2-=1;}
    else if(z2<0 && z1!=0) {z2+=100; z1-=1;}}
    else if(sign(y1)==-1 && z1==0){z2*=-1;if(z2==0)z3*=-1;}}
}
```

Также прикрепляю [Excel](https://products.aspose.app/cells/ru/viewer/view?FolderName=384d1d2e-9acf-4afb-925e-58eefed0cc11&FileName=Tests.xlsx&Uid=6728fd30-fd99-4706-a018-635e604fff77.xlsx) файл со всеми тестами

Comment: а чем 100-ричная система отличается от десятичной?) это же одна и та же система. просто надо интерпритировать результаты по-разному.

Comment: Вот здесь товарищ делал миллиардную систему счисления: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1320695/3380

Comment: @pavel Здравствуйте,можно подробнее?

Comment: @MuradMammadzada а что подробнее. вам нужно сложить 1 25 68 и -1 77 99 что тоже самое, 12568 - 17799 = -5231 -> -52 31. и всё. все операции можете в десятичной делать.

Comment: @pavel Хорошо, а если у меня число 56 1 77 и 23 8  4 === 56177 + 2384 = 58561, что теперь? получится 58 56 1? У меня же посередине просто 9-ка.

Comment: @pavel или если у меня 3 2 2 и -4 2 1, ответом будет -99 99, а Вашим методом если попробовать,не получится. Давайте обсудим и это, если Вам не трудно.

Comment: @MuradMammadzada, всё получается: 30202-40201=-9999.

Comment: @pavel Понял. Осталось еще 2 вопроса.  1) Можете продемонстрировать Ваш метод на числа -1 97 0 и 98 10.      2) Мой код совсем плох?  Я хотел общий случай вывести, а потом методом перегрузки операторов написать код для решения подобной задачи.

Comment: Не понимаю... у вас же в Excel'евском файле четко показаны формулы перевода чисел — почему вы ими не воспользуетесь?..

Comment: О, @Harry , я Вас ждал. Ну почему не пользуюсь,еще как пользуюсь,просто вопрос в другом. Я хочу написать общий случай, одной формулой. Да и мне тут говорят,что можно забить на все это и делать все процессы через 10-ричную систему счисления(Комментарии выше). А Вы что скажете, опираясь на свой опыт?

Answer (score 1):

Для *конкретно* 100-ричной системы счисления *десятичная **запись*** получается путем последовательной записи "цифр" в десятичной системе

```
83 1 15 2₁₀₀ == 83011502₁₀
```

а обратный перевод в 100-ричную — разделением справа налево на двойки десятичных цифр.

Так же, как какая-нибудь двоичная запись восьмеричного числа получается путем последовательной записи восьмеричных цифр как бинарных (а назад — соответственно троек бинарных цифр).

```
4 5 6₈ == (100 101 110) == 100101110₂
```

Просто как для систем по основанию `A` и `Aⁿ` — с группировкой по `n` разрядов справа налево.

Ну, а в общем случае — естественно, число получается чтением цифр с последовательным умножением на основание системы счисления, и в конце — на знак. Т.е. если у вас есть массив `xᵢ`, где знак — только у `x₁`, то значение получается, грубо говоря, как

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При реальном вычислении удобно использовать схему Горнера. Например, пусть ваше число записано в виде массива `int x[N];`, где знак "минус" может присутствовать только у первого значения. Тогда

```
int X = abs(x[0]);
for(int i = 1; i < N; ++i) X = X*10+x[i];
if (x[0] < 0) X = -X;
```

Для диапазона ваших значений в Excel'евском файле это самое простое решение — получать значение из 100-ричной записи, выполнять нужную операцию и обратное преобразование — получая цифры *справа налево* как (псевдокод)

```
int Y = abs(X);
while(Y)
{
    очередная цифра = Y % 100;
    Y /= 100;
    if (Y == 0) очередная цифра *= -1
}
```

Если же числа *большие*, явно не влазящие даже в `long long int` — тогда надо реализовывать длинную арифметику "в столбик", с переносами при необходимости между разрядами. В вашем случае максимум четырех 100-ричных цифр, т.е. значений до 100000000, я такой необходимости не вижу, а потому и не рассматриваю.

Comment: Тогда уточните и формализуйте задание, что именно надо сделать и *как*. Без этого все разговоры, как говорится, в пользу бедных...